# How do I update the integer while the loop is running?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

When we enter 0 in the program it is supposed to stop running the loop and print the average of the numbers. When I run the program and initially enter 0, the program exits. If I enter in an integer that is not zero first, and then enter 0, the program keeps running and I can't quit.I figure that the integer value needs to update when the user enters a new value for the program to quit, and the sum to be correct.

How do I update the integer value while the loop is running? I should change or add something in the loop I'm guessing.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise05_01 {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        float negCount = 0;

        float sum = 0;

        float posCount = 0;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a positive or negative integer. Entering 0 ends program");

        int integer = input.nextInt();

        while (integer != 0) {
            if (integer > 0) {
                posCount = +1;
                sum = +integer;
            }
            if (integer < 0) {
                negCount = +1;
                sum = +integer;
            }

            float count = negCount + posCount;

            if (integer == 0) {
                System.out.println("The answer");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to ask for input from inside the loop. Also those assignments to `posCount`, `negCount`, and `sum` aren't doing what you think they are

Comment: Maybe you should step out of the while loop using break

Comment: Weird, I cannot edit this question to format the text....

Answer (score 2):

There are *two* problems.

First, you don't get any input while you're in the loop.  That's fixable with a suggestion provided earlier by Lunchbox.

Second, this is not accumulating the value:

```
posCount = +1;
```

That assigns a positive 1 to `posCount` every time.

You want to either increment the value...

```
posCount++;
```

...or add one explicitly.

```
posCount += 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add the line that gets input in your while loop.

```
    while (integer != 0) {
        integer = input.nextInt();
           .
           .
           .
```

This way while the loop is running, every iteration it will check for an input still.

Also I have to say this looks suspiciously like homework... especially the class name...

Answer (score 1):

As [Lunchbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26151287/3457753) points out in his answer, you need to request input from the user from inside your loop, otherwise `integer` never changes and you never exit your loop; the behaviour you're observing is the program running forever.

The best way to do this is Lunchbox's suggestion:

```
int integer = input.nextInt();
while(integer != 0){
    // Do stuff
    integer = input.nextInt();
}
```

However, you have many other problems with your code. For one thing, why are you using `float`s to store your counters and sum values? Why not use `int`s?

For another, you're never actually incrementing those values. As [Makoto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26151702/3457753) points out in his answer, the line `posCount = +1` is not an increment operator.

In that case, the `+` operator is the [unary plus operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html). What this will do is force your signed value to be positive, so `+(-1) == 1`. While this is useful, it's not what you want to happen, and it's *definitely* not what you want to be doing around your sum.

Instead, you want to do one of the following three things:

```
posCount = posCount + 1;
posCount += 1;
posCount++;
```

Those are all equivalent statements. The `++` operator is the postfix increment operator, which will add 1 to the value of the variable and then return it (It's slightly more complicated than that, but you can read that on your own time). So don't use that syntax for your sum; use one of the other two.